# Is CLWB and PCOMMIT instructions available in gcc? If yes, in which version?

Tags: linux, x86, kernel, intel, instruction-set

Are Intel's non-volatile memory instructions CLWB and PCOMMIT available in gcc ? If yes, starting from which gcc version are they available?

Comment: Do you mean Intel intrinsics? (Intel's intrinsics guide doesn't list any for those insns)  Or gcc `__builtin_something()`?   GNU C inline asm lets you use arbitrary asm instructions.  Of course, the assembler has to understand them, unless you use `.byte` pseudo-instructions to emit the encoding yourself.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @peter: Apologies for late reply. I am looking for the gcc version in which the assembler can understand CLWB and PCOMMIT instructions. I do agree that we can directly use their byte codes in the code but from the version on which they are available this would not be necessary.